# How do I get the original characters with python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ascii, lxml

I am making a personal rss reader using lxml's etree but am having trouble converting back to the original characters. I am expecting to see "World Cup 2014: With Júlio César’s Help":

```
url = 'rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml'
xml = etree.parse(url)
for x in xml.findall('.//item'):
    text = x.find('.//description').text
    print text
    # 'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\u2019s Help'
    text = text.encode('utf-8')
    print text
    # 'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\u2019s Help'
    text = text.decode('utf-8')
    # Error: 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character....'
```

I have read [Python's Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) as well as [Joel's Unicode Intro](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) but I must be missing something.

EDIT: Almost there many thanks to unutbu...just need help converting \u2019:

```
content = 'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\u2019s Help'
html = LH.fromstring(content)
text = html.text_content()
print text
print(repr(text))
print text.encode('utf-8')

##RESULTS##
World Cup 2014: With Júlio César\u2019s Help
u'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\\u2019s Help'
World Cup 2014: With Júlio César\u2019s Help
```

Comment: Are you printing to something which knows how to handle unicodes?  (i.e. not ```cmd``` or similar console)

Comment: I would like to display it in the browser

Comment: did you try `text.decode("latin-1")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the `UnicodeEncodeError`, I believe `text` is a `unicode`:

```
text = u'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\u2019s Help'
text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

reproduces the error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xfa' in position 22: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

In Python2, [lxml sometimes returns `str` for text, and sometimes `unicode`](http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-does-lxml-sometimes-return-str-values-for-text-in-python-2). 
Indeed, you'll see this unfortunate behavior if you run this script:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import urllib2

url = 'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml'
xml = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for x in xml.findall('.//item'):
    text = x.find('.//description').text
    print(type(text))
```

prints

```
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
<type 'str'>
<type 'unicode'>
...
```

However, it only returns a `str` when the text is composed of plain ASCII values (i.e. byte values between 0 and 127).

Although in general one should never encode `str`s, encoding a `str` composed of
byte values in the 0-127 (ASCII) range using `utf-8` preserves the `str`.

So you can actually handle both the `str` and `unicode` the same way by encoding *both* with `utf-8`, as though `text` were always `unicode`.

Since the `text` is really HTML, below I've used `lxml.html` to reduce the HTML to plain text content. This too can be either a `str` or `unicode`. That object, `text`, is then encoded before printing:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import lxml.html as LH
import urllib2

url = 'http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml'
xml = ET.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url))
for x in xml.findall('.//item'):
    content = x.find('.//description').text
    html = LH.fromstring(content)
    text = html.text_content()
    print(text.encode('utf-8'))
```

Note that in Python3, lxml always returns a unicode, so purity of thought is restored.

---

**How the UnicodeEncodeError occurs:**

```
text = u'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\u2019s Help'
text = text.decode('utf-8')
# Error: 'UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character....'
```

Note first that this is an **UnicodeEncodeError** even though you asked Python to **decode** `text`.
Further note that the error message says Python was trying to use the `ascii` codec.

That is a classic sign that the problem has to do with [Python2's automatic conversion between `str` and `unicode`.](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Suppose `text` is a unicode. If you call

```
text.decode('utf-8')
```

then you are asking Python to perform a no-no -- decoding a unicode. Python2, however, tries to accommodate you by silently first *encoding* the unicode using the `ascii` codec before decoding using `utf-8`. This automatic conversion between `str` and `unicode` was meant to be a convenience for dealing with str and unicode with values only in the ASCII range, but it enables mental unclarity since it encourages programmers to forget about the difference between str and unicode and it only sometimes works -- when the values are in the ASCII range. You get an error when the values fall outside the ASCII range -- and this is what you've encountered.

In Python3, there is no automatic conversion between `bytes` and `str` (or what in Python2 parlance is `str` and `unicode`, respectively). Python simply raises an error when you try to encode `bytes` or decode `str`. Mental clarity is restored, at the cost of forcing programmers to pay attention to the type. As this question shows, however, that cost is really inescapable even with Python2.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer but it doesn't seem to get the apostraphe at the end. I get: "World Cup 2014: With Júlio César\u2019s Help"

Comment: Please change `print(text.encode('utf-8'))` to `print(repr(text))` and show us what is printed.

Comment: u'World Cup 2014: With J\xfalio C\xe9sar\\u2019s Help'

Comment: Can you post the actual code you are running? It doesn't occur (for me) with the code I posted, and I'm at a loss why you are seeing a different result.

Comment: If `content` is a `str`, then the desired output can be obtained using `content = content.decode('unicode_escape')` but I can hardly believe that is the right answer. The problem seems to be due to either some mistake in the XML served by rss.nytimes.com, or in lxml or in the code defining `content`. When I go to `rss.nytimes.com` I do not see the same content you are seeing. Can you post a snippet of XML -- the entire `<description>...</description>` element which contains `World Cup 2014: With Júlio César’s Help`? Maybe then I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post the `repr(...)` of the XML `str`, since that will give an unambiguous representation.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mixture of Latin-1 (\xfa) and Unicode (\u2019) in a single string. The Python encoding methods can't handle that.